# The tablelist curselection goes at calling the directory dialog

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have the test code:

```
package require Tk
package require tablelist

set ::tv {{N1 qwe} {N3 rty} {N4 uio}}
set ::dir [pwd]
tablelist::tablelist .tbl -columns {0 Name 0 Value} -listvariable ::tv
button .but -text "Directory..." -command {
    set sel1 [.tbl curselection]
    set sel2 [.tree selection]
    tk_messageBox -message ".tbl curselection = \"$sel1\"\n\n.tree curselection = \"$sel2\""
    set ::dir [tk_chooseDirectory -initialdir "$::dir"]
}
ttk::treeview .tree -columns Value
.tree heading "#0" -text "Name"
.tree heading "#1" -text "Value"
foreach t $::tv {
    lassign $t t1 t2
    .tree insert {} end -text $t1 -values $t2
}
.tbl selection set 0; #.tbl activate 0
.tree selection set I001
pack .tbl .tree .but -side left -anchor n -padx 9 -pady 9
```

At first pressing "Directory" button, I see "tablelist curselection=0" okay.

But at calling the directory dialog, the tablelist curselection disappears. The treeview selection remains, as it should be.

I couldn't find how to make the tablelist curselection to be untouched.

tablelist v6.8
TIA

[image: 1 step]
[image: 2 step]
[image: 3 step]

Comment: Can't replicate, I'm on tablelist 5.13 however and Tcl 8.6.7

Comment: I've updated tablelist to 6.8 but still cannot replicate.

Comment: I'd tried it on Windows 10, ActiveTcl 8.6.8 - no issue, all works okay.

Comment: But on Debians 9.9 (Tcl/Tk 8.6.6), 10.0 (Tcl/Tk 8.6.9), bullseye/sid (Tcl/Tk 8.6.10) the issue still remains.

Comment: Somehow only tk_chooseDirectory behaves this way on Debian, while tk_getOpenFile, tk_getSaveFile, tk_chooseColor don't produce this issue,

Comment: Hmm ok, I don't have a debian desktop to test, sorry :(

Comment: Sounds like something subtle in selection handling, possibly triggered by some weird Xdefaults on Debian with that particular X desktop configuration. Try disabling exporting of the (PRIMARY) selection by the tablelist.

Comment: Thank you, Donal! Indeed, the disabling exporting solves the problem, i.e. ```.tbl configure -exportselection false```.

Comment: Maybe, the following link would help when a selection exporting would be wanted at this configuration: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/listbox%20selection

Answer (score 0):

This sort of weird behaviour is the kind of thing that occurs when several widgets are fighting over the [`PRIMARY` selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection#Selections), a feature of X11 which is used to mean that only one widget at a time has anything selected. (It also used to be used a lot for select-and-paste style text manipulation, but that's fallen out of favour and the more cross-platform `CLIPBOARD` style selections are used for that sort of thing.) I've no idea why it is turning on in your specific case and not elsewhere, but it's probably something to do with defaults in the X properties on Debian; that's not very visible but can be listed with this [shell command](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/x_resources#Default_settings).

```
xrdb -query -all
```

Tk widgets support the `PRIMARY` select by default (on X11; it's not really meaningful on other platforms) and many third-party and synthetic widgets do as well, but they can be told not to by setting the standard boolean `-exportselection` option on the widget to any false value. Once that's done, the widget continues to maintain a notion of what it has selected but does not export that notion outside of itself (unless you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or something like that).

```
tablelist::tablelist .tbl -columns {0 Name 0 Value} -listvariable ::tv \
        -exportselection false
```